# Matlab remoteParallelFunction and Mex file Error

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, local, mex, parfor

I'm trying to validate the default local matlab parallel configuration, but I get the following error:

> Validation Details
>
> Configuration: "local" Type: local
>
> -------------------------------------- Stage: Find Resource
>
> Status: Passed Description:  Validation passed
>
> Command Line Output: (none)
>
> ---
>
> -------------------------------------- Stage: Distributed Job
>
> Status: Passed Description:  Validation passed
>
> Command Line Output: (none)
>
> ---
>
> -------------------------------------- Stage: Parallel Job
>
> Status: Passed Description:  Validation passed
>
> Command Line Output: (none)
>
> ---
>
> -------------------------------------- Stage: Matlabpool
>
> Status: Failed Description:  Encountered a problem while trying to run
>   code in the matlabpool.
>
> Command Line Output: Starting matlabpool using the 'local'
>   configuration ... connected to 8 labs.
>
> Error Report: Error using ==> parallel_function at 598 Error in remote
>   execution of remoteParallelFunction : RUNTIME_ERROR
>
> Debug Log: (none)
>
> ---

And if I actually try to run the code, I receive the following error:

```
??? Invalid MEX-file
'/usr/local/matlab/R2010a/toolbox/distcomp/private/dctRegisterMpiFunctions.mexa64':
/usr/local/matlab/R2010a/toolbox/distcomp/private/../../../../../bin/glnxa64/libmwmpi.so:
undefined symbol: _ZN9MathWorks6System9Condition9signalAllEv.

Error in ==> remoteParallelFunction at 51
    dctRegisterMpiFunctions('mwmpi');

??? Error using ==> parallel_function at 598
Error in remote execution of remoteParallelFunction : RUNTIME_ERROR

Error in ==> InterpCorrectionPar at 53
        parfor n=1:size(Image,3)

Error in ==> InterleaveDetCor at 119
                FixedImage=InterpCorrectionPar(ImStack,Int,Tr,varargin{Ctrl});

Error in ==> MainCompareProgram at 25
InterleaveDetCor(FilePath,SavePath,RunCorrection,'FiltShift','Cubic','Spline','Linear','Sinc');
```

I'm running matlab 2010a on a gnome 2.28.2 linux "server" (really just a computer with 400Gigs of memory and 32 processors used for intensive computation).  The code I'm running is just a few parfor loops that I've run on my local machine before.  I'm actually running the program on the server computer locally through vcn.  Can anyone please suggest what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

The 'undefined symbol' error coming from a part of your MATLAB installation is a very bad sign. You may well need to re-install.